# How can I create a traffic light status column

Tags: column, calculated-column, task-list, status

I want to create a traffic light status column in my task list. I have referenced the [Path to SharePoint solution](https://blog.pathtosharepoint.com/2008/09/01/apply-color-coding-to-your-sharepoint-lists/) (and most of the others out there) but using a calculated column to display HTML and then using code on the page to render that HTML only works if my task list is set to the basic table style, which won't work for me b/c it hides the toolbar and the quick access to views and also does not allow sub-tasks to be indented below their parents. The other main problem with this is that if someone wanted to sort the list by the traffic light status, the values are shown to them as HTML code which would be confusing.

Is there an easier way to create a traffic light status field? Ideally it would just be a drop-down field where a user selects the colored circle that they want. Is this possible? If not, does anyone know of a way to create a traffic light status column that does not require the list view style to be "basic table?"

For reference, I am currently working in SharePoint 2016 beta

Comment: Not an easier way; You have to go the Client Side Rendering (JavaScript) programming route... but, as it looks now CSR won't be available anymore in future SP versions. Microsoft has replaced CSR technology with SPFx